# Elmah does not save username in HttpRequestValidationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah

I'm using this Filter to log HttpRequestValidationException in Elmah :

```
public class ElmahRequestValidationErrorFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception.InnerException);
    }
}
```

and i registered this Filter in FilterConfig.cs :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahRequestValidationErrorFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

But when this error occurs, UserName of The User That is Authenticated don't save in elmah logs on User Column.But in other Error's it dose work true.
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Is the error logged at all? I just tried to recreate your setup, but in my case, username is logged successfully.

Comment: Also be aware that ELMAH doesn't support raising a null as the exception. This means that if InnerException is null, your filter itself will throw an exception and the original error are never logged to your ELMAH log.

Comment: i tried to context.Exception but again doesn't Rise Username...

Comment: I think you need to post some more details. What version of MVC are you using? Are you using Web API. Are you using some of the contrib packages for ELMAH (like Elmah.MVC)?

Comment: Yes, in The All of Errors Work it Successful but in this Case (HttpRequestValidationException), it doesn't work...

Comment: MVC 5 and install-package Elmah 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

user column in Elmah is empty becuase Elmah get username from

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

You can set current user before Elmah log the error.

```
try 
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 string userName = "username1";  
 string[] roles = { "" };
 Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), roles);
 ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```